# How to make a directory by JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, web

I use the EclipseEE IDE to write JSP.
Now there is a problem about making the directory.
[problem]
I write the function about making one directory in JavaBean, and I use the relative path.
But the directory is always made under the directory of the EclipseEE software, rather than the position where my intent.
[code]

```
String userDirString="./User/";
File userDir=new File(userDirString);    
if(userDir.mkdir()){
      ..........
}else{
      ..........
}
```

I really want program to create the directory under the WebContent directory, but it doesn't work,

I also try to the other method to implement this function-----writing it by JSP not javabean. But it does not work either.

So what should I do, now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a relative filepath, relative to the app/app container/etc.

Also, the `WebContent` directory is a *project* directory, not a web app directory.

You should write to an absolute, configurable directory.

Not also that writing *into* a web app's directories isn't necessarily a great idea, as (1) the directory may be deleted when the app is re-deployed, and (2) isn't even possible if you deploy the app as a war file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I determine to use the absolute, configurable directory........

Answer (score 2):

Following code on JSP will give you the path to webroot

```
String pathToWebRoot = application.getRealPath("/");
```

It is not preferable to write java code on jsp

Comment: What is the "apolication"? Do I need use my Project name to replace it? EclipseEE show me a red line under the word -- application.

Comment: application is an implicit object available in jsp

Comment: But if I want to write this function in the javabean, how should I do?

Comment: @Peter - Its an *object* of `javax.servlet.ServletContext` and you may pass it to non-servlet class via method parameter however it is should be avoided and I'm agree with Dave Newton.